# What is involved in adding to the standard Python API?

Tags: python, api

What steps would be necessary, and what kind of maintenance would be expected if I wanted to contribute a module to the Python standard API?  For example I have a module that encapsulates automated update functionality similar to Java's JNLP.

Comment: should be community wiki

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please look at [Python PEP 2](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0002/) for details. You'll surely find more necessary information at the [PEP Index](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/), such as [PEP 1: PEP Purpose and Guidelines](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0001/).

Have a look through the PEP index for previous PEPs which may have been rejected in the past.

Of course you should also consult the [python-dev mailing list](http://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/python-dev).

Comment: Also, make your code available as a 3rd party package first, preferably at pypi.

Answer (score 2):

First, look at modules on pypi.  Download several that are related to what you're doing so you can see exactly what the state of the art is.

For example, look at `easy_install` for an example of something like what you're proposing.

After looking at other modules, write yours to look like theirs.

Then publish information on your blog.

When people show an interest, post it to SourceForge or something similar.  This will allow you to get started slowly.

When people start using it, you'll know exactly what kind of maintenance you need to do.

Then, when demand ramps up, you can create the pypi information required to publish it on pypi.

Finally, when it becomes so popular that people demand it be added to Python as a standard part of the library, many other folks will be involved in helping you mature your offering.